# Getting the error "Query input must contain at least one table or query."

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

I am using visual studio 2010 to create a form where you can edit,delete, or insert data from an accessdatabase. When I try to run the form in a web browser I get the error "Query input must contain at least one table or query." I believe that the problem lies with my code/syntax but I am unable to determine the cause of the problem. I added some of my code below and any help/hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
            DataFile="~/App_Data/database.accdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [database]"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [database] WHERE ([EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID)"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [database] SET [Phone]=@Phone,[FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName]= @LastName  WHERE ([EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID)"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [database] (Phone,FirstName,LastName) VALUES (@Phone,@FirstName,@LastName) WHERE ([EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID)">
            <InsertParameters>
             <asp:formparameter name="Phone" formfield="tbPhone" />
             <asp:formparameter name="FirstName"  formfield="tbFirstName" />
             <asp:formparameter name="LastName"  formfield="tbLastName" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID"
            AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateInsertButton="True"
            EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." Width="372px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone"
                     SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
                    SortExpression="LastName" />

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>        
    </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        Phone Number: 
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /> 
        First Name:
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br /> 
        Last Name:&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br />           
        <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="New Employee" onclick="InsertEmployee" />
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is [Database]?   Is that your table name?  You need to specify a table name, such as PERSONS, or Employees?

```
SELECT * FROM [database]
```

try something like

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
```

Try this now

```
SELECT Phone,FirstName,LastName,EmployeeID FROM [employees]
```

If that works, it means some sort of field in the Employees table is something that can't be handled...  Since the above triggers an error, it means the code can't handle an Autonum field.   Try the following:

```
SELECT Phone,FirstName,LastName,CAST(EmployeeID as INT) as EmployeeID 
       FROM [employees]
```

Try taking the where clause entirely off the INSERT SQL

```
  InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [database] (Phone,FirstName,LastName) VALUES (@Phone,@FirstName,@LastName) "
```

Comment: yeah, database is the name of my table.

Comment: I suspect that might be causing an issue, Database is usually a reserved word.   Can you copy the records from that table into another table and change your code to reference the new table name?   If that works, then the driver is probably getting tripped up on the reserved word....

Comment: I have a new table named Employees like you suggested but I still get the error.

Comment: Your code looks OK, this message generally means the query has a syntax error.   Try replacing the * with the 3 field names you need, it could be a data type in the table that ACCESS can't handle...

Comment: The datatypes for the three fields that are visible are "TEXT", the EmployeeID is the primary key, not visible on the table, and its datatype is "AutoNumber." So I should just put "SELECT Phone,FirstName,LastName  FROM [employees]"? If the syntax for the last sentence is correct, I get a error "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'EmployeeID'." Also, thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: Well, the fact that you are getting something back is a good thing.   I've edited the Answer above to tweak your SQL statement.

Comment: After trying your latest suggestion I get a new error "IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)."

Comment: Do you think the problem might lie with my .vb page? I looked over it and Visual Studio tells me that my insert operation inserts as an Integer.                                                                                                  `Protected Sub InsertEmployee(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click`
        `AccessDataSource1.Insert()` @Sparky

Comment: That got rid of the error! When I add a new entry into my database now, two blank rows are inserted but no data is added. Should the "VALUES" be the ID's of the text boxes? For example would it be `VALUES (tbPhone,tbFirstName,tbLastName)` @sparky